# Find $t$ in $i = 50\sin\left(120\pi t -\frac{3\pi}{25}\right)$ where $i = 25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics, mathematical-physics

> An alternating current generator produces a current given by the equation
>   $$i = 50\sin\left(120\pi t - \frac{3\pi}{25}\right)$$
>   where $t$ is the $\text{time}$ in $\text{seconds}$.
>   **(Q) Find the first two values of $t$ when $i = 25 \text{ amperes}$**
>   
> <sub>[[src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBX81.jpg)]</sub>

Is my working correct? Kinda stuck with this problem, what do I do next?

$50\sin(120\pi t-3\pi/25)= 25$

$\sin(120\pi t-3\pi/25)= 25/50$

$\sin(120\pi t-3\pi/25)= 0.5$

$\text{Ref angle }= \sin^{-1}(0.5)$

Since $\sin(120\pi t-3\pi/25)= 0.5 > 0$, it is at $1^{\text{st}}$ or $2^{\text{nd}}$ quadrant

$(120\pi t-3\pi /25)=\pi/6$

Comment: If $\pi/6$ is the reference angle, what is it's corresponding 2nd quadrant angle? Given the 2 angles, now it's just a matter of solving for $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $x=120\pi t-3\pi/25$. If $x=\theta $ is one
solution of the equation $y=\sin x$ then another solution is $x=\pi -\theta $.(*)

**Complete solution using your work**. If the hint isn't enough, hover your mouse over the grey to see

You have correctly found the first angle $\theta >0$ for which $\sin \theta =1/2$. It's $\arcsin 1/2=\pi /6\in \left[0,\pi /2\right] $.

> The first value of $t$ when $i=25\,  \textrm{A}$ (I denote $t_{1}$) satisfies your last equation.

\begin{equation*}
120\pi t-\frac{3\pi }{25}=\frac{\pi }{6}.
\end{equation*}

> Simplify by dividing both sides by $\pi $\begin{equation*}120t-\frac{3}{25}=\frac{1}{6}\end{equation*}and solve it

\begin{equation*}
t=t_{1}=\frac{1/6+3/25}{120}=\frac{43}{18\,000}\text{ }\mathrm{s}\approx
2.389\text{ }\mathrm{ms}
\end{equation*}

Since in general $\sin x=\sin \left( \pi -x\right) $, we have

> \begin{equation*}\sin (\pi /6)=\sin \left( \pi -\pi /6\right) =\sin (5\pi /6).\end{equation*}

Hence $\theta _{2}=5\pi /6\in \left[ \pi /2,\pi \right]$ is the second angle $\theta>0$ for which $\sin \theta =1/2$.

> As a consequence, and similarly to $t_{1}$, the second value of $t$ when $i=251 \, \textrm{A}$ (I denote $t_{2}$), is the solution of the equation

\begin{equation*} 120\pi t-\frac{3\pi }{25}=\frac{5\pi }{6},\end{equation*}

> which is

\begin{equation*}
t=t_{2}=\frac{5/6+3/25}{120}\text{ }\mathrm{s}=\frac{143}{18\,000}\approx
7.944\text{ }\mathrm{ms}
\end{equation*}

--

(*) The general form for the solutions $x$ of $y=\sin x$ combine both
solutions $x=\theta ,x=\pi -\theta $ added to any multiple of $2\pi $. So $
x=2k\pi +\theta ,k\in \mathbb{Z}
$ and $x=\pi -\theta +2k\pi =(2k+1)\pi -\theta ,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ are solutions, which can be written in a single expression as $x=n\pi
+(-1)^{n}\theta $, $\theta \in \left[ -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right] $ and $n\in 
\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 1):

You're right so far =) 
Now, you need to consider the angle which lies in Quadrant II to obtain your $2^{\text{nd}}$ value for $t$

You *could* use the fact $\sin\theta = \sin(\pi - \theta)$ because if $\theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, then $\pi - \theta \in \left(\frac{\pi}{2} , \pi\right)$

Just to stimulate analytical thinking of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions, let us consider a general equation  for alternating current:
$$i = \mathcal A\sin\left(\omega t + \phi\right) \implies t = \frac{1}{\omega}\left( \arcsin \frac{i}{ \mathcal A} - \phi\right)$$

Here, in the calculation of $t$, we have constricted $\frac{i}{\mathcal A} \in \left[-1, 1\right]$ inorder to use the $\arcsin(x)$ function which only spits out angles in the first quadrant        ( from $0 \text{ rad}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ rad}$)

This gives us *one* value for $t$ but what about the second answer? 
Well, consider $\omega t + \phi \in \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right)$ . 
For which value in that range would $\sin(\omega t + \phi) = \sin(\arcsin \frac{i}{\mathcal A})$ ?

Use the fact that $\sin\theta = \sin\alpha \iff \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n\alpha\  , n \in \mathbb  Z$ in such a way as to get your required angle which lies in the second quadrant.

But note this, we could have effortlessly developed a general equation for all $t$ by considering that:
$$\sin(y) = x \iff y = n\pi + (-1)^n\arcsin x$$

Hence,
$$t_n = \frac{1}{\omega}\left(n\pi + (-1)^n\arcsin \frac{i}{\mathcal A} - \phi\right)\ ,\, n\in\Bbb Z$$

Make the substitutions
$
\begin{align}
\omega &= 120\pi \text{ rad/s}\\
i &= 25 \text{ amp}\\
\mathcal A &= 50 \text{ amp}\\
\phi &= - \frac{3\pi}{25} \text{ rad}
\end{align}
$
and find the values of $t_{(n=1)}$ and $t_{(n=2)}$

Comment: `you need to consider the angle` $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ `which lies in the second quadrant to obtain your second value for $t$.` I've found $\pi-\pi/6=5\pi/6$ instead, because $\sin\pi/6=\sin5\pi/6=1/2$, and the first value for $t$ is $\pi/6$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Whoops, that was a gross mistake. I've corrected it. Thanks :D